# Review Board extension for mercurial not working on a Windows machine

Tags: mercurial, review-board

I have installed mercurial and review board extension for mercurial on my Windows XP machine. In review board, I have added a repository say "MyRepo" which is on a central server.
I cloned "MyRepo" to my local machine, modified a file for testing and committed to my local repo. I haven't yet pushed it to my central repo.

Now I run "hg postreview" on my cloned local repo. I select "MyRepo" when postreview asks me to choose a repo.

I get a "File not found (207)" error after the command completion. Howver, my review request is uploaded to Review Board server but the diff file is not. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong or is there a patch or command I am not aware of?
I am a novice in DVCS and mercurial, so any help on this matter is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already pushed changes or did more than one commit to the clone (that diffs now more than one commit). Try this and refer to the changeset you created the clone from:

hg postreview -l -o --parent={changeset}

If you wan’t to submit further editings refer to the rewiewid and changeset your first postreview command submitted:

hg postreview -e {reviewid} -o --parent={changeset}